# Hadoop word count example without root permissions

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to run this hadoop word count example on a Linux machine without root permissions. I keep getting this error all the time, though.

```
13/08/27 16:00:08 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:priyankara cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTrackerNotYetInitializedException: JobTracker is not yet RUNNING
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.checkJobTrackerState(JobTracker.java:5199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getNewJobId(JobTracker.java:3543)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTrackerNotYetInitializedException: JobTracker is not yet RUNNING
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.checkJobTrackerState(JobTracker.java:5199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getNewJobId(JobTracker.java:3543)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy2.getNewJobId(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy2.getNewJobId(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:944)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

What is happening? How can I fix this?

I think the problem is I don't have root permission on that machine. Is there a way to run this example without root permission or not?

Comment: Have you started the job tracker yet? You might want to check the job tracker logs (location varies depending on your distro / installation method) to see why the error message `JobTracker is not yet RUNNING` is being displayed above (file permission errors, HDFS isn't running, ...)

Comment: can you please tell me where can i find my jobtracker logs and how can  I check those..

Comment: What distro of hadoop are you using, how / where did you install it?

Comment: hadoop-1.2.1 I have installed it home/apps/hadoop-1.2.1

Comment: Look in `/home/apps/hadoop-1.2.1/logs/*-jobtracker-*.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by editing the etc/hosts file.

We have to put our Ip address and host name to /etc/hosts file.
example ,
If your Ip is 192.255.50.1 then your user name is 'user' you have to put them both on your hosts file as ,

```
192.255.50.1 user
```

Comment: Please describe *how* you edited `etc/hosts`; this answer isn’t really useful to anyone else as it is.

Comment: you have to open your terminal. Then type    [gedit /etc/hosts] command and hit enter. I have used gedit as the text editor you can replace it with your editor (vi/vim.....)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your hostname, is it "localhost" or different name?

You can try to change the host name to be "localhost", than re-start the Hadoop. For instance,

```
$ hostname localhost

$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/stop-all.sh

$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-all.sh
```

This works for my case. For your information, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use minicluster on Windows , 
this suggestion of  192.255.50.1 user fixed my issue , I put 127.0.0.1 myloginname(user). it fixed my issue of Datanode denied communication with namenode: 
thanks DilanG